# /dev/ttyS* permission denied

Tags: kernel, 15.10

Answers posted so far have not really addressed a good solution.
Just installed 15.10 and get permission denied on bootup or reboot, even after changing them to crw-rw-rw from crw-rw----!

Answer (score 1):

You need to add the current user to `dialout` group.

Run

```
sudo usermod -aG dialout $USER
```

Then you will be allowed to write to `/dev/ttyS*` after log off and log on.